# Собирайте вещи(,) и давайте убираться отсюда

Tags: пунктуация

Следует ли ставить запятую?
Собирайте вещи(,) и давайте убираться отсюда.

Comment: Настя, мы тут комментами поясняющими обросли, загляните в гости.

Answer (score 1):

Запятая не нужна, здесь однородные члены предложения, а не ССП. Об этом свидетельствует одинаковое наклонение в обеих частях.

Между однородными членами предложения, связанными одиночными соединительными союзами *и, да* (в значении ‘и’), *да и,* запятая не ставится.

Comment: Сержик, почитай мой ответ: я тебе возражаю. )))

Answer (score 0):

Запятая нужна, у нас ССП.

И наклонения у нас разные: *собирайте* - повелительное, *давайте убираться* названо "побудительной конструкцией".

Валгина рассказывает (по ссылке - подробности):

[Побудительными называются предложения, выражающие волеизъявление говорящего, их цель - побуждение к действию.](http://www.hi-edu.ru/e-books/xbook089/01/part-010.htm)

---

[Если глаголы в предложении имеют разные наклонения и соединены союзом «и», между ними ставится запятая, так как они не могут быть однородными.](https://pishugramotno.ru/punktuacia/znaki-prepinaniya-v-slozhnosochinyonnom-predlozhenii)

Comment: *Запятая не нужна* — так нужна или не нужна?

Comment: Фу. Спасибо, друг. Вестимо, НУЖНА. Исправляю по товарищеской наводке. Мерси боку.

Comment: Галина, зачем вы в моём вопросе запятую поставили?

Comment: Тёмыч, я не помню, об чём речь. Если переусердствовала, отыграй, пожалуйста.

Comment: Уже отыграл. Я про вопрос про плюш и плис. ;)

Comment: @Galina Avanesova, в обоих частях повелительное наклонение. Побудительные предложения выражаются в форме повелительного наклонения. Запятая не нужна.

Comment: Увы, Сержик, нет. Но правил я не знаю. Практик мы.

Comment: @ Galina Avanesova, правило как раз есть в вашей первой ссылке. В русском языке всего три наклонения.  Поэтому говорить об отдельном наклонении неверно.

Comment: А, вредный Сержик. Ну давай заменим "давайте" на *начнём, валяйте, айда, мигом*, и не будет никакого общего наклонения.

Comment: @ Galina Avanesova,термин наклонение используется в нескольких значениях: словоизменительная грамматическая категория (обозначения глагольных форм (изъявительное, повелительное, сослагательное), и шире (как аналог термина "модальность") - как обозначение целеустановки высказывания, типа отношений высказывания к действительности.

Comment: [Модальность](http://rusgram.ru/node/59#1)

Comment: Сержик! Ты знаешь: правил я никаких не знаю. Ну хоть ты дерись, это разные наклонения. Вот смотри: абсолютная смысловая и какая угодно совпадающая оттеночность: *Собирайте вещи(,) и давайте убираться отсюда. - Собирайте вещи, и начнём убираться отсюда. - Собирайте вещи, и будем двигать отсюда. - Собирайте вещи, и станем делать ноги отсюда.* Нет, ты мне разницу покажь. Или даже две большие.

Comment: Так. Чивой-то я намудрила... Вот што ета: *абсолютная смысловая и какая угодно совпадающая оттеночность* О_о Кароч: полное смысловое совпадение, в какой стилистике ни изгаляйся. *Собирайте вещи, и марш отсюда без оглядки; Собирайте вещи, и чешем отсюда*...

Comment: Галина, понимаете, в русском языке три наклонения. А если следовать вашей логике, получается 4 наклонения.  А грамматическим средсвом выражения побудительного предложения является повелительное наклонение. К тому же и в учебниках конструкция с  частицей "давайте" также относится к повелительному наклонению.

Comment: Вы путаете синтаксис и морфологию. У Валгины синтаксис. Откройте, пожалуйста, раздел Морфология у Валгины - и убедитесь сами.

Comment: Вот цитата из преведенной вами ссылке из Валгины. оформления побудительных предложений являются: 1) побудительная интонация; 2) ***сказуемое в форме повелительного наклонения***; 3) специальные частицы, вносящие побудительный оттенок в предложение (давай, давайте, ну-ка, да, пусть).

Comment: Вот именно, Сержик, последний твой коммент  - за меня, только не выделенный тобой пункт 2, а третий - о побудительных частицах. Частица немножко не сказуемое. ))

Comment: Частица присоединяется к сказуемому в повелительном наклонении.